# Не получается получить объекты из Json

Tags: java, json

Не выводит значения из БД на сервере

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(json_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {

                if(JSON_STRING != null){


                    try{

                        final JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(JSON_STRING);
                        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
                        {

                            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                            KEY_NAME_EVENT = json_data.getString("KEY_NAME_EVENT");
                            KEY_INFO_EVENT =json_data.getString("KEY_INFO_EVENT");
                            KEY_CONTACT =json_data.getString("KEY_CONTACT");
                            KEY_ADRESS = json_data.getString("KEY_ADRESS");



                        }

                    }catch(JSONException e1){
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }



                }



                stringBuilder.append(KEY_ADRESS);


            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();


        }catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
```

type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Пожалуйста, укажите строку на которой происходит ошибка. Дополнительной полезной информацией будет значение JSON_STRING в момент когда возникает ошибка.

Comment: Просто для анализа - прикрутите GSON (google JSON конвертер), скормите ему проблемную переменную и выведите в консоль. Какая структура у получаемого объекта будет? Или просто на каждом шагу выводите toString() для объекта. Посмотрите, может Вам возвращается JSONArray, с которым надо работать как-то иначе? Например его разбирать придётся.

Comment: JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); ошибка в этой строке

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject`
У Вас там не объект, а массив

Comment: JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); здесь ошибка

Comment: Вы получаете объект из массива, а судя по тексту ошибки ваш массив состоит из массивов, а не из объектов.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена! Проблема была в php файле к которому обращается Json, вернее в одной строчке: echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response)); изменил на :
echo json_encode($response);